# How to call "reg delete KEY /f" from C#

Tags: c#, registry

Please save my sanity by explaining to me why my code doesn't work, cause currently I'm in (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ mode.

**Quest:** Delete registry key without prompting from C#.
**Requirement:** Do it by calling cmd.exe -> "reg delete KEY /f" from C#
**Why:** Just because I want to know why it doesn't work for me lol... for now, I admit defeat and resort to Microsoft.Win32.Registry.DeleteSubKey

I have a basic console application with the following method:

```
    private static int RunCmd(string command)
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo cmdsi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
            cmdsi.Arguments = command;
            Process cmd = Process.Start(cmdsi);
            cmd.WaitForExit();
            return 0;
        }
        catch
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

I'm calling it to delete a registry key for my MS Office Addin, like so:

```
RunCmd(@"/c reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\...\MyAddin /f");
```

**Problem**: It doesn't work (key not deleted).

Now, **the key exists** and I'm running the program that executes this **as Administrator**, so it's not that. Now, if you change the executing line to read:

```
RunCmd(@"/k reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\...\MyAddin");
```

... the command window will appear, you can clearly see it's run as administrator and you will be asked if you want to delete the key with its name pasted in front of you just as you wanted it. If you answer yes, you will be told that
**ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.**

Now the biggest joke of all - copy paste the

---

reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE...\MyAddin /f

---

bit into an elevated cmd prompt and run it. **It will run just fine and the key gets deleted**.

WTF?
Anybody?

Comment: Possibly a 32-bit vs. 64-bit issue? The key you want to delete belongs to a 64-bit app, and you're running on a 64-bit version of Windows, so the command prompt you launch is a 64-bit process, but your app is a 32-bit process?

Comment: Nailed it! That was the solution.
Please post it as an answer so I can throw some rep at you ;)

Comment: Unchecking "prefer 32 bit" in project -> properties -> build tab solved the problem... but still waiting for you to submit this as an answer ;)

Comment: You can also pass the `/reg:64` flag to the `reg` command. But I would strongly recommend using the normal API for this, rather than shelling out to the `reg` command. Anyway, glad that worked for you. I don't need the rep; feel free to write your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cody Gray answered in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851573/how-to-call-reg-delete-key-f-from-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment74739107_43851573) above, the issue had to do with 32bit v 64bit. Having unchecked "prefer 32bit" option in Project Properties -> Build tab fixed the issue.